# Changing .active class and aria-current="page" dynamically based on active webpage

Tags: php, html, web, bootstrap-5

I'm building a website while also trying to keep changing code an easy task.
For that, I include the navbar with 
`<?php require_once('./includes/navbar.php'); ?>` so that I only need to change the `navbar.php` to see changes site-wide.

I also use **Bootstrap 5** and let it take care of styling the currently active page by using 
`<a class="active">` (and also using the recommended `aria-current="page"` attribute).

Now my problem is that I need to somehow dynamically apply the above mentioned class and tag to only the active page. I have no idea how to do that in an elegant way but thought that this might be possible in PHP?

Does somebody know how to do it?

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kzv719sr/) to see code of the navbar

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and managed to fix my problem with a little bit of javascript code which you can just add with `<script></script>` tags anywhere in the html code:

1. Give every link in the navbar html a unique id (e.g. `id="pricing"`).
2. Add `class="active"` to active page and Bootstrap.css will style that element accordingly.
3. Remove `class="active"` from the other pages/links which are not active.
4. Set `aria-current="page"` to active page and set `aria-current="none"` to inactive pages.

```
in navbar.php:
<a id="home" class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Home</a>  <!-- 1. -->
<a id="pricing" class="nav-link" href="pricing.php">Pricing</a> <!-- 1. -->

in pricing.php:
<script>
        var pricing = document.getElementById("pricing");
        pricing.classList.add('active');                  //2.
        pricing.setAttribute("aria-current", "page");     //4.
        
        var home = document.getElementById("home");
        home.classList.remove('active');                  //3.
        home.setAttribute("aria-current","none");         //4.
</script>
```

Hope this may help someone else too.